# When overloading == in C#, is there a practical use case for overloading != as something other than "return !(a == b);"?

Tags: c#

I always wondered why you have to overload both; couldn't the implementation of `!=` be built-in to call `==`? Is there a reason where you'd want "quantum indeterminate equality", if you'd like to call it that - situations where both `x == y` and `x != y` are true, or both false?

Comment: Floating point has "quantum indeterminate equality" due to NaN.

Comment: Define "practical". I've seen lots of crazy things in code, and some people would insist it makes the code better, more efficient, easier to write, or whatever. I could see someone claiming that they want to overload `==` to get an object-content-equality comparison, but want to leave `!=` so that they can do implicit reference-equality comparisons. The marked duplicate has lengthy discussion on the topic. If you really think you have a new question, please explain in detail why the existing questions on the topic don't address your particular concern.